# Python URL join beginning with ////

Tags: python, url, urllib

In HTML, we find URLs like `////assets.example.com/some/ressource`.

A web browser on page `https://www.example.com/original/page` will construct the following URL from that:

```
https://assets.example.com/some/ressource
```

But when using the URLjoin method in python

```
from urllib import parse
parse.urljoin("https://www.example.com/original/page", "////assets.example.com/some/ressource")
```

we get

```
https://www.example.com//assets.example.com/some/ressource
```

Why do web browsers behave different than the URLjoin method here? Who is right here?

Comment: Those two do different things - the code joins using a `base` page and an additional sub-path. If you want do have your base changed, you need `parse.urljoin("https://www.example.com/original/page", "//assets.example.com/some/ressource")` because Python needs `//` and not `////`. Your `////assets.example.com/some/resource` on a page just makes the browser recognize it should go to `https://assets.example.com`, since `//` just means [protocol-relative pathing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) (and browsers are probably being nice by not caring you have 4 `////` in a row.

Answer (score 0):

On the question of "who is right?" The major difference in this is that Python is stricter about what you're giving it than browsers are when it comes to respecting URLs per [RFC-9386](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986).

But note that `urllib.parse.urljoin` does something more specific than just "parse URLs for correctness" because its purpose is to construct an **absolute** URL from what you give it. When you give it `////...`, it ends up with a parsed URI that doesn't have a `netloc` (or host, as you will) so behaviorally, it has to fall-back on using the base URL to see if it has a domain to construct an absolute URL.

And if you wanted to achieve the same thing as how a browser would do it, use the 'expected' format of just `//host/path` rather than more than two `/`, like so...

```
new_url = parse.urljoin(
    "https://www.example.com/original/page", 
    "//assets.example.com/some/resource"
)
print(new_url)

# output
# https://assets.example.com/some/resource
```

Read further if you want to dive into the internals of how Python parses URIs for `urljoin()`.

---

When you call `urljoin`, it starts off by parsing the URLs you pass it using `urllib.parse.urlparse`:

```
# urllib.parse.urljoin
def urljoin(base, url, allow_fragments=True):
    """Join a base URL and a possibly relative URL to form an absolute
    interpretation of the latter."""
    if not base:
        return url
    if not url:
        return base

    base, url, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(base, url)
    bscheme, bnetloc, bpath, bparams, bquery, bfragment = \
            urlparse(base, '', allow_fragments)
    scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = \
            urlparse(url, bscheme, allow_fragments)
    # ...
```

We can dive into how URLs are parsed, and inside `urllib.parse.urlparse`, it executes the following:

```
# urllib.parse.urlparse
def urlparse(url, scheme='', allow_fragments=True):
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
    splitresult = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
    scheme, netloc, url, query, fragment = splitresult
    
    if url[:2] == '//':
        netloc, url = _splitnetloc(url, 2)
        if (('[' in netloc and ']' not in netloc) or
                (']' in netloc and '[' not in netloc)):
            raise ValueError("Invalid IPv6 URL")
```

With `_splitnetloc` being:

```
# urllib.parse._splitnetloc
def _splitnetloc(url, start=0):
    delim = len(url)   # position of end of domain part of url, default is end
    for c in '/?#':    # look for delimiters; the order is NOT important
        wdelim = url.find(c, start)        # find first of this delim
        if wdelim >= 0:                    # if found
            delim = min(delim, wdelim)     # use earliest delim position
    return url[start:delim], url[delim:]   # return (domain, rest)
```

Take all this code together, and when you pass it something of the form `////name/path`, the URL parser finds `//` to start, and then tries to find the `netloc` with the subsequent string `//name/path`, which `_splitnetloc` determines would be `('', '//name/path')` because it searches for the first `/` possible to denote the `path` of the URL.

So see that your two `assets.example.com` URLs would be parsed differently based on this logic:

```
In [1]: four = "////assets.example.com/some/ressource"
In [2]: two = "//assets.example.com/some/ressource"
In [3]: pfs = urllib.parse.urlparse(four, "https")
In [4]: pts = urllib.parse.urlparse(two, "https")

In [5]: print(pfs)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='', path='//assets.example.com/some/ressource', params='', query='', fragment='')

In [6]: print(pts)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='assets.example.com', path='/some/ressource', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

The absence of the `netloc` is important because, going way back to the beginning when I talked about `urljoin`, the subsequent code after it performs the `urlparse` of the two input URLs, is this:

```
if scheme in uses_netloc:
    # this is the netloc from the second argument URL
    if netloc:
        return _coerce_result(urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path,
                                          params, query, fragment)))
    netloc = bnetloc
```

And so, with `////assets.example.com/...`, the parsed URL doesn't have a `netloc` and so it ends up that you use the base URL domain (`netloc = bnetloc` line).

Whereas with `//assets.example.com/...`, it does have a `netloc` so the code just immediately returns `urlunparse(...)` on the parsed URL, resulting in a url like `https://assets.example.com/...`.